# Github Action : golang cannot find package

Tags: go, github-actions

I set sample github action to my repository. snippet is here.

```
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    - name: Set up Go 1.x
      uses: actions/setup-go@v2
      with:
        go-version: ^1.13
      id: go

    - name: Check out code into the Go module directory
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Get dependencies
      run: |
        go get -v -t -d ./...
        if [ -f Gopkg.toml ]; then
            curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
            dep ensure
        fi
```

but job is fail where `Get dependencies`. error is here.

```
package github.com/<organization-account>/<repo-name>/api/domain/repo: cannot find package "github.com/<organization-account>/<repo-name>/api/domain/repo" in any of:
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.14.4/x64/src/github.com/<organization-account>/<repo-name>/api/domain/repo (from $GOROOT)
    /home/runner/go/src/github.com/<organization-account>/<repo-name>/api/domain/repo (from $GOPATH)
```

of course. My code is work at local when `go run main.go`. I have `go.mod`, `go.sum`.

Comment: `go run` might work, but the problem is with `go get -v -t -d ./...`. Is your `<repo-name>` private?

Comment: thank you for reply. yes. my repository is private.

Comment: Looks like actions/checkout@v2 doesn't out your code into the GOPATH, and the name indicates that it's expecting to clone a [module](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules). If you can convert to a module this would be much simpler. Otherwise you have to make sure that you're checking out into the correct place in GOPATH.

Comment: thank you reply. how do i convert private repo to module?

Answer (score 3):

> This is not a correct answer for the OP, but may help someone reaching here from searching.

In the root of your go project:

```
go mod init
go mod tidy
```

Commit and push to github, and it should work now.

Comment: then delete the two files

```
Gopkg.toml
Gopkg.lock
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: this isn't even close to the answer, he's getting 404's trying to download private repos @DavidPi

Comment: @ChadGrant You are absolute correct. I checked the date of my answer and OP, seems I missed that important info. I updated my reply as it maybe relevant to people coming from search engine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a token for go get or go mod to download private repos, thats why you're getting a 404.

First, you need to add the private repos to the GO_PRIVATE environment variable.

```
env:
  GO_PRIVATE: github.com/<organization-account>/*
```

Then you need to configure git to use that token.

```
- name: Setup Git
  run: git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.TOKEN }}:@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com"

- name: Get dependencies
      run: go mod download
```

Add the token to the actions secrets in github.com

I don't use dep, but you should use go mod download instead of go get or dep since you have a mod file. I don't know why you're using dep AND go modules AND using go get at the same time. Weird.